# how do I get this following result in sql 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Table 1

2 columns

```
pack no     20  20  20  20  20  20  30  30  30  30  30
Serial no   12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22
```

Result I need is

```
pack no      20        30
serial no    12-17     18-22
```

Comment: Are the values 20 and 30 static, or are there other values?

Answer (score 0):

if these fields are all numbers,

```
SELECT  packNo,
        CAST(min_serial AS VARCHAR(12)) + '-' + CAST(min_serial AS VARCHAR(12)) serial_no
FROM
        (
            SELECT  packNo, 
                    MIN(serialNo) min_serial,
                    MAX(serialNo) max_serial
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY packNo
        ) subtable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `min()` and `max()` functions to do that. It would be better if you use underscore in column names instead space.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27704/2)**

```
select [pack no], convert(varchar(10),min([Serial no])) + '-' + 
                  convert(varchar(10),max([Serial no])) as [Serial no]
from yourTable
group by [pack no]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
    [pack no], 
    CAST(MIN([Serial no]) AS NVARCHAR(10))+'-'+CAST(MAX([Serial no]) AS NVARCHAR(10)) as [Serial no]
from 
    YourTable
group by [pack no]
```